# How to pass user variables from TFS 2015 Build definition to power shell script?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2015, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

I am working on vNext builds TFS 2015. How can we pass a user defined variable from vNext build to power shell script? I am adding powershell script as a step in the build definition.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can define build variables, then reference them in the PowerShell task under arguments.  For example if my powershell script took a parameter called foo I could do this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks Dylan for the answer. I tried above but it is not working for me. I am trying to do a simple robocopy and pass the folder name using the build arguments and build variables. it is not accepting the folder name : for ex robocopy C:\temp\abc\ C:\temp\xyz\$foldername\  I am passing $foldername through arguments and user variable...Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I thought you said you are running a powershell script? did you write your powershell script to accept parameters? if not you need to do that first.

Comment: Thabnks Dylan, I added param ($foldername) and it started working. The script does what it is supposed to do, but the build is failing. There is no information in the logs as well and my definition has only one step Powershell. the only error message i get is : "Task PowerShell failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details."

Answer (score 1):

You Can access the V next user variables in power shell like below,

Example:

```
$env:foo
```

In your case it is,

```
blah.ps1 -foo $env:foo
```